# php mysql bootstrap rows button/div height

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap-3, height

I'm having a problem getting equal heights.

I use php mysql to generate n number of rows of a bootstrap grid, 6 items(buttons/divs) per row.

Id like each of the items(buttons/divs) in the row to be the same height.

I'm not having success, When i add the jquery code below it flattens my items(buttons/divs).

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">

<?php

while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo "<div class=\"row\">";
$item = 2;
foreach ($result as $resulty) { 
echo "<div class=\"col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 buttonMus\">";
echo "<img src=\"directory/".$resulty['foo'].".png\">";
?>
<input type="checkbox"  class="single-checkbox" name="Mus[]" 
value="<?php echo addslashes($resulty['musloc']); ?>" />
<?php
echo $resulty['musloc']. ' ';
echo "<br>";
echo "</div>"; // for xs
if($item % 5 == 1) { // i.e. Count is divisible by 5
echo "</div>"; // for row
echo "<div class=\"row\">"; 
} // if item
$item++;

} //for each
echo "</div>";
} // while

?>
<input type="submit" name="submit"    value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
```

i have tried putting this jquery code at the top and the bottom of the php but both places it flattens the items(divs/buttons)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var maxHeight = -1;

$('.buttonMus').each(function() {
 maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
});

$('.buttonMus').each(function() {
 $(this).height(maxHeight);
});
});

</script>
```

Can any one help to resolve this problem.

Any comment or answer will appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited to add an image that was there but i didnt think was relevant (so left out), 

but i think it is, it affected the height i think, its still not perfect though, one div is a bit longer than the others.

Answer (score 0):

please check this code

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   var itemArray    =   $(".row").find(".buttonMus");
   if(itemArray.length>0){
     var maxHeight  =   $(itemArray[0]).height();
     for(var i=0;i<itemArray.length;i++){
        if(maxHeight<$(itemArray[i]).height()){
            maxHeight   =   $(itemArray[i]).height();
        }
     }
     $(".buttonMus").height(maxHeight);
   }
});
```

OR you can use this match height plugin
https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height

Comment: Hi, Thank you, I think the css of the divs caused the problems. I had to do this.

`.buttonMus {
    vertical-align: top;
    min-height: 12px;
    /*important keeps em in row*/
    display: inline-block;
    }
    `
and put the buttonMus(s) in a wrapper div.
`#wrapperMus {
    overflow-x: scroll!important;
    /* the whitespacenowrap has to be there or the div heights dont work*/
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    }
    `
and finally, put the jquery, in the index page, the php code at top is and 'include' in the index page.